# How to redirect users to a different page/URL on a SharePoint save button click in New item form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, development, office-365, spservices

I am having an issue about redirecting users to a different URL on Save or Cancel button. First of all I have used below code to change SharePoint list new item form's Save button to Submit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ChangeSPSavetoSubmit()");
function ChangeSPSavetoSubmit()
{
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)
 {
    if(inputs[i].type == "button" && inputs[i].value == "Save")
     {
      inputs[i].value = "Submit";
     }
  }
 }
</script>
```

Above is a working solution, its added as a script editor web part on new item form.
Below is the code I added as well on the new item form to redirect users to a different page/URL on Submit/Cancel button clicks.

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">      

$(document).ready(function() {
     $('input[value=Submit]').click(function() {     
        window.location.replace("https://***.sharepoint.com");  
      });   
     $('input[value=Cancel]').click(function() {       
        window.location.replace("https://***.sharepoint.com");  
      });  
    });
</script>
```

The functionality works when clicked on Cancel button but not when clicked on Submit button, can someone please help with the correct code. Thanks in advance, FYI I am working with O365/SPOnline.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the issue is not related to your code, it's related to the default behavior of `New item` Link.

> When you click on the new item link the page redirects to the
>   `NewForm.aspx` with the `?Source=` query string holds the URL of     `ALLItems` view URL, it is the page URL that you come from.

**So** to handle the redirect after clicking the `Submit` button, you should handle the `New item` link rather than the `Submit` button.

---

1. Open and Edit `All items` page,
2. Add `Script Editor` with the below script

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

   document.getElementById("idHomePageNewItem").onclick = function() {
window.location.href= "http://ListURL/NewForm.aspx?Source=http://the reirect url"; 
   }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84455/discussion-on-answer-by-mohamed-el-qassas-mvp-how-to-redirect-users-to-a-differe).

Answer (score 1):

Add below JavaScript code on Newform/EditForm by adding content editor / script editor web part

For NewForm

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  history.pushState({
               id: 'onetIDListForm'
             }, 'List Name - New Item', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/Lists/List Name/NewForm.aspx?Source="+_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/SitePages/PageName.aspx");

});
```

For EditForm

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 history.pushState({
                id: 'onetIDListForm'
                }, 'List Name - Edit Item', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/Lists/List Name/EditForm.aspx?ID=" + CurrentItemID + "&Source="+_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/SitePages/PageName.aspx");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script to redirect the page to another page after submitting item.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var button = $('input[name$="SaveItem"]');  
button.removeAttr("onclick");  
button.click(function() {  
    var elementName = $(this).attr("name");  
    var aspForm = $("form[id=aspnetForm]");  
    var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action;  
    var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);  
    var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, "https://<page>");
    if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;  
    WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Joanna, thanks so much for the script. I tried it but for some reason its not working. i simply changed the url part to https://www,google.com. Do I have to make any other changes? Please let me know, thanks.